# how to store two single dimensional array values into jdbc java bean values and stored it into mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, pojo

here I get Student id get correct format but their status i got last value only
my java bean code

```
String[] arr1=new String[1000]; //stuid
     if(aa!=null)
     {
         arr1=aa.split(",");
     }
      String[] arr = new String[1000]; //status
     if(ss!=null){
         arr = ss.split(",");
     }
             for(int j=0;j<arr1.length;j++)
             {
                    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                     {
                        bb.setStuid(arr1[j]); 
                        bb.setStatus(arr[i]);
                        bb.setSid(sid);
                         bb.setCid(cid);
                         bb.setTtid(ttid);
                         bb.setDate(date);
                         bb.setDid(did);
                         bb.setHour(hour);
                     }
                    bb=ad.AddAttendance(bb);
         }


    return bb;

}
```

> see my images

and my mysql inserted value is 
[result page in mysql database (wrong value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axQjh.jpg)

But, what I want exactly 
[correct data show in front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMIit.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always looping the entire `arr` array for each of the `arr1` element. And that's why for each stuid, status is the last value (since the last value is stored inside `bb.setStatus()` when the inner loop completes for one studId).

You have to use single loop. And I think you will get your desired result.

```
String[] arr1=new String[1000]; //stuid
if(aa!=null)
     {
         arr1=aa.split(",");
 }
  String[] arr = new String[1000]; //status
 if(ss!=null){
     arr = ss.split(",");
 }
         for(int j=0;j<arr1.length;j++)
         {

                bb.setStuid(arr1[j]); 
                bb.setStatus(arr[j]);  // It will take status of j'th studId
                bb.setSid(sid);
                bb.setCid(cid);
                bb.setTtid(ttid);
                bb.setDate(date);
                bb.setDid(did);
                bb.setHour(hour);
           }
           bb=ad.AddAttendance(bb);
     }


    return bb;

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope this will work.

You should only use `single for loop`.

```
String[] arr1=new String[1000]; //stuid
     if(aa!=null)
     {
         arr1=aa.split(",");
     }
      String[] arr = new String[1000]; //status
     if(ss!=null){
         arr = ss.split(",");
     }
             for(int j=0;j<arr1.length;j++)
             {

                        bb.setStuid(arr1[j]); 
                        bb.setStatus(arr[j]);
                        bb.setSid(sid);
                         bb.setCid(cid);
                         bb.setTtid(ttid);
                         bb.setDate(date);
                         bb.setDid(did);
                         bb.setHour(hour);

                    bb=ad.AddAttendance(bb);
         }


    return bb;

}
```

Comment: dear sir / madam, here i need two single dimensional array needed 1. status(present or absent) and 2. studentid . that's why I use two for loops

Comment: Yes correct but my question is , sequence of stdid and stdstatus is same aa and ss?